# Неявное поведение spring при работе с дженериками

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot

Есть некая сущность Report и одна из ее реализаций:

```
public class CCReport extends AbstractReport<CCReportRow> {

    public CCReport(List<CCReportRow> rows, LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
        super(rows, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<CCReportRow> getRowClass() {
        return CCReportRow.class;
    }
}
```

Есть некий интерфейс сервиса:

```
public interface ReportService<T extends Report> {
    T createReport(LocalDate from, LocalDate to);
}
```

У него есть несколько реализаций в зависимости от типа `Report`:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CCReportService implements ReportService<CCReport> {

    private final CCReportsExportRepository repository;

    @Override
    public CCReport createReport(LocalDate from, LocalDate to) {
        return repository.generateReport(from, to);
    }
}
```

Далее есть абстрактная реализация слушателя RabbitMq:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractReportTaskListener<T extends Report> implements ReportTaskListener<T> {

    protected final ReportService<T> reportService;
    //-------------------//    

    @Override
    public void processReportTask(SingleReportRequest<T> reportRequest) {
        Report report = reportService.createReport(reportRequest.getFrom(), reportRequest.getTo());
        //-------------------//
    }
}
```

И непосредственно сама реализация этого слушателя:

```
@Component
public class RabbitCCReportTaskListener extends AbstractReportTaskListener<CCReport> {

    public RabbitCCReportTaskListener(
            ReportService<CCReport> reportService,
            ReportMailService mailService,
            ReportToExcelService excelService,
            ReportsNameGenerator nameGenerator,
            WebDavStorageService webDavStorageService) {
        super(reportService, mailService, excelService, nameGenerator, webDavStorageService);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = RabbitConfig.CC_QUEUE, concurrency = "2-2", autoStartup = "true")
    @Override
    public void processReportTask(SingleReportRequest reportRequest) {
        super.processReportTask(reportRequest);
    }
}
```

При запуске всего этого добра через gradle bootRun все запускается без проблем, однако, если создаю docker-образ вылетает ошибка:

> *********************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.reports.service.RabbitCCReportTaskListener required a single bean,
>   but 2 were found:
>    - CCReportService: defined in URL [jar:file:/app/reports.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/reports/service/CCReportService.class]
>    - SRReportService: defined in URL [jar:file:/app/reports.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/reports/service/SRReportService.class]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
>   to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
>   that should be consumed

В конце концов приходится явно описывать бины через @Qualifier и тогда начинает работать. Подскажите, с чем может быть связано такое поведение?

**UPD:**
Вот [ссылка на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603291/how-to-autowire-bean-of-generic-type-t-in-spring), где уже описывали подобный вопрос. Плюс есть несколько статей по запросу "spring generic bean autowire"

Comment: добавь код обявления SRReportService, CCReport, SRReport

Comment: @VladMamaev репорт добавил, хотя не вижу глобального смысла в этом. SRReportService - все то же самое, что и CC, только параметризован явно другим классом и лезет в свой отдельный репозиторий.

Comment: а версии финального билда совпадают с теми что и при bootRun?

Comment: Это связано с тем, что спрингу не достаточно определение бинов, так как есть, поэтому он их выбрать не может. В этом проявляется некая двусмысленность, которая недопустима в рантайме.

Comment: @VladMamaev да, версии однозначно совпадают.

Comment: @RomanC в том и дело, что при запуске через bootRun все работает замечательно. Плюс, в моей практике был проект, где мы использовали данный подход в продакшене

Answer (score 3):

Это случается из-за [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): при компиляции `ReportService<CCReport>` вырождается в `ReportService<Report>`, и здесь возникает неоднозначность в рантайме, т.к. таких бинов уже 2. Чтобы избежать ситуации используйте либо конкретный наследник ReportService либо @Qualifier в конструкторе конкретного наследника AbstractReportTaskListener.

В докер упакованы все jar-файлы проекта и все зависимости. Локально, вероятно, не все скомпилировано, попробуйте пересобрать проект начисто.

Comment: Пересобирал - это не влияет на нормальную локальную работу. Как писали в telegram канале spring'a: "Я помню, что после какой-то версии ждк 1.7 этот функционал спринга сломался.
Не знаю починили ли его". Плюс, доподлино известно что данный подход работает на "проде", т.к. я сам лично его использовал на одном из проектов

Comment: Вот очевидный пример того, что данная функциональность доступна: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603291/how-to-autowire-bean-of-generic-type-t-in-spring. Другой вопрос, почему оно перестало нормально работать?

Comment: @I.Perevoz ваш случай не такой же как в примере по линке которую вы добавили, можете посмотреть это видео
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KABC7Fty3x8 
Здесь немного похожая на вашу ситуация, и детально расказывают про Type Erasure